# Bash: pipe 'find' output into 'readarray'

Tags: bash, find

I'm trying to search for files using `find`, and put those files into a Bash array so that I can do other operations on them (e.g. `ls` or `grep` them). But I can't figure out why `readarray` isn't reading the `find` output as it's piped into it.

Say I have two files in the current directory, `file1.txt` and `file2.txt`. So the `find` output is as follows:

```
$ find . -name "file*"
./file1.txt
./file2.txt
```

So I want to pipe that into an array whose two elements are the strings `"./file1.txt"` and `"./file2.txt"` (without quotes, obviously).

I've tried this, among a few other things:

```
$ declare -a FILES
$ find . -name "file*" | readarray FILES
$ echo "${FILES[@]}"; echo "${#FILES[@]}"

0
```

As you can see from the `echo` output, my array is empty.

So what exactly am I doing wrong here? Why is `readarray` not reading `find`'s output as its standard input and putting those strings into the array?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

When using a pipeline, bash runs the commands in subshells¹. Therefore, the array is populated, but in a subshell, so the parent shell has no access to it. You also likely want the `-t` option so as not to store that line delimiters in the array members as they are not part of the file names.

Use process substitution:

```
readarray -t FILES < <(find .)
```

Note that it doesn't work for files with newlines in their paths. Unless you can guarantee if won't be the case, you'd want to use NUL delimited records instead of newline delimited ones:

```
readarray -td '' < <(find . -print0)
```

(the `-d` option was added in bash 4.4)

---

<sup>¹ except for the last pipe component when using the `lastpipe` option, but that's only for non-interactive invocations of `bash`.</sup>

Comment: In order to support newlines, this is sufficient: `readarray -d '' < <(find your_args -print0)`

Comment: @VasyaNovikov Support for `-d` in `readarray` seems to be relatively recent. (Like the Redhat on my workplace doesn't know it yet.)

Answer (score 8):

The correct solution is:

```
unset a; declare -a a
while IFS= read -r -u3 -d $'\0' file; do
    a+=( "$file" )        # or however you want to process each file
done 3< <(find /tmp -type f -print0)
```

That's similar to what [Greg's BashFAQ 020](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020) explains in detail and [this answer covers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1120952/2350426).

Has no problem with odd named files (that contain no NUL in the name), with spaces or new lines. And the result is set in an array, which makes it useful for further processing.

Comment: Great, this is a better solution to the problem I was trying to solve in the first place. +1 as soon as my rep reaches 15 :)

Comment: Why does this use 3 instead of stdin? Also I believe `-d ''` is more usual (the 0 will terminate the string anyway, so it's in effect a 0-length string.) Also I guess the first line could replaced with just `a=()`.

Comment: @ddekany, using fd 3 means you leave standard I/O 0, 1, 2 fds untouched so they can be used by commands within the loop. That's good practice.

Comment: @ddekany, using `a=()` instead of `unset a; declare -a a` wouldn't work properly if `a` was previously declared as an associative array which may be why the OP chose that approach.

Answer (score 3):

`readarray` can also read from stdin

```
readarray FILES <<< "$(find . -name "file*")"; echo "${#FILES[@]}"
```

Comment: This doesn't work with `find -print0` for protecting against "unexpected" file names.

Comment: `readarray` **always** reads from stdin unless you use `-u` to specify a different fd. The difference here is that you're using `<<<` to set its stdin instead of `|` or `<`.

Answer (score 1):

With `shopt -s lastpipe` the solution shown in the original question works, as then the part after the last `|` runs in the same process as most of the script:

```
shopt -s lastpipe

# This is just the code form the original question.
# Of course it could be done with -print0, etc.
declare -a FILES
find . -name "name*" | readarray -t FILES
echo find and readarray exit status: "${PIPESTATUS[@]}"
echo "${FILES[@]}"
echo "${#FILES[@]}"
```

This however is only practical if `lastpipe` can be made a project-wide standard (maybe you already have such common setup for `set -u`, etc.). Also know that `lastpipe` only works for non-interactive shells.

The other typical pipe replacement, `< <(...)` (process substitution), has the problem that it's quite hard to check if the child process has succeeded.

Comment: You can always do `readarray -td '' a < <(find . -print 0); readarray_status=$?; wait "$!"; find_status=$?` or `if readarray -td '' a < <(find . -print0) && wait "$1"; then echo OK; else ...; fi`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas But `$?` will reflect the exit code of `readarray`, so even if `find` failed, that will be still `0`. I also tried this to be sure (although without `-td ''` and `-print0`, as `-td` is not yet supported by `readarray` where I'm).

Comment: in `bash` process substitutions are started as background jobs which sets `$!`, so you can use `wait "$!"` to retreive their status. Try `bash -c 'readarray < <(exit 3); wait "$!"; echo "$?"'`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Bash is more determined to ruin process substitution than that. (: It says "pid X is not a child of this shell", where X is the PID of the subshell. I actually don't know why.

Comment: Indeed I can reproduce with very old versions. Looks like it was fixed in 4.4

Comment: Ah. Bash 4.2.46 (RHEL 7.9, quite recent) still has that bug. Anyway, I think it's a quite risky approach even with later Bash, because if somebody later introduces a sub-process inside the while loop, it breaks.